# The image size of last product in my PHP ecommerce website is smaller

Tags: php

I'm writing a PHP ecommerce website by referencing to other PHP ecommerce website (I used same image folder for both websites), however the image of last product is displayed in different size. Can somebody help with this? [my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeqpJ.png).

The code for my website is here:

```
<?php

$conn = $pdo->open();

try{
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = :catid");
$stmt->execute(['catid' => $catid]);
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
$image = (!empty($row['photo'])) ? 'images/'.$row['photo'] : 'images/noimage.jpg';
        echo "
<li class='element no_full_width' data-alpha='Curabitur cursus dignis' data-price='20000'>
<ul class='row-container list-unstyled clearfix'>
<li class='row-left'>
<class='container_item'>
<img src='".$image."' class='img-responsive' alt='Curabitur cursus dignis'>
</a>
<div class='hbw'>
    <span class='hoverBorderWrapper'></span>
</div>
</li>
<li class='row-right parent-fly animMix'>
<div class='product-content-left'>
    <a class='title-5' href='product.php?product=".$row['slug']."'>".$row['name']."></a>
    <span class='spr-badge' id='spr_badge_1293239619' data-rating='0.0'>
    <span class='spr-starrating spr-badge-starrating'><i class='spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty' style=''></i><i class='spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty' style=''></i><i class='spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty' style=''></i><i class='spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty' style=''></i><i class='spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty' style=''></i></span>
    <span class='spr-badge-caption'>
    No reviews </span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class='product-content-right'>
    <div class='product-price'>
        <span class='price'>
        $".number_format($row['price'], 2)." </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='list-mode-description'>
     Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis amet voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus quis nostrum. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum dolorem necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed...
</div>
<div class='hover-appear'>
    <form action='#'' method='post'>                        
        <div class='effect-ajax-cart'>
            <input name='quantity' value='1' type='hidden'>
            <button class='add-to-cart' type='submit' name='add'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i><span class='list-mode'>Add to Cart</span></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class='product-ajax-qs hidden-xs hidden-sm'>
            <div data-href='./ajax/_product-qs.html' data-target='#quick-shop-modal' class='quick_shop' data-toggle='modal'>
                <i class='fa fa-eye' title='Quick view'></i><span class='list-mode'>Quick View</span>                                                                       
            </div>
        </div>
    <a class='wish-list' href='./account.html' title='wish list'><i class='fa fa-heart'></i><span class='list-mode'>Add to Wishlist</span></a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
        ";
}
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$pdo->close();

?>
```

This is the website im referencing [referenced website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37dBo.jpg)

And the code of the referenced website is here:

```
<?php

$conn = $pdo->open();

try{
    $inc = 3;   
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = :catid");
$stmt->execute(['catid' => $catid]);
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $image = (!empty($row['photo'])) ? 'images/'.$row['photo'] : 'images/noimage.jpg';
    $inc = ($inc == 3) ? 1 : $inc + 1;
        if($inc == 1) echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='box box-solid'>
                    <div class='box-body prod-body'>
                        <img src='".$image."' width='100%' height='230px' class='thumbnail'>
                        <h5><a href='product.php?product=".$row['slug']."'>".$row['name']."</a></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class='box-footer'>
                        <b>&#36; ".number_format($row['price'], 2)."</b>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ";
        if($inc == 3) echo "</div>";
}
if($inc == 1) echo "<div class='col-sm-4'></div><div class='col-sm-4'></div></div>"; 
if($inc == 2) echo "<div class='col-sm-4'></div></div>";
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$pdo->close();

?>
```

Comment: Ok - so on the screen shots it's a different size. The original image might be a different shape, or the CSS classes might differ in some way. There's no way to tell from the screen shot and your PHP code is not really relevant here.

Comment: Looks, I'm doing a little modification from the referenced website and code into my website. I'm not sure why you are saying the php code not relevant when it's the code that's printed out the output for both images attached above.

Comment: PHP runs on the server. It's not responsible for the presentation. It's clearly putting the correct image in the correct location in the HTML. After that it's the browser that handles the presentation working from the original file and the CSS that's applied to it. My guess is that the image is a different shape, but PHP neither knows nor cares about that.

Comment: Oh you are right, so I readjust the image size and everything looks good now. Thank you!